# Forgot to file form 8889 with HSA self contribution of only $0.01, what's the consequences if I don't file amended return?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, hsa, form-1040x

I filed a 1040NR-EZ tax return in 2018. later on I realized that I had an HSA opened in 2017 which requires Form 8889 and the non-simplified 1040NR to be filed. my own HSA contribution was $0.01.

I might not file an amended form as the difference in AGI is merely 1 cent. My only concern is that if I don't do this way, IRS might not recognize the established date for this HSA since the agent never saw form 8889 in the beginning. In this case, if in later year I wanna reimburse myself for the eligible medical expense, will IRS question when my first HSA was established?

Comment: Your logic seems sound.  What was the motivation for opening an HSA with a penny contribution?

Comment: As a matter of fact I didn't intend to contribute any but the HSA bank needs employee's contribution first to establish an HSA account. The default is $0.01 deducted from employee's payroll. My company contributed a few hundreds to it later in the year. That's the whole picture of the story.